# What is it in SVG file?

Tags: svg

I was looking into SVG code, and i see that first time:

```
<svg id="Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 342 472"><defs><style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}</style></defs><title>Artboard 1</title><image id="Vector_Smart_Object" data-name="Vector Smart Object" class="cls-1" width="314" height="200" transform="translate(14 272)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAToAAADICAYAAAB4by36AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAcrklEQVR4Xu2dbXfjKLNFDwWS08///623Ewuo+wHhKJ6knTg6vEjstWYm3UujyBJsVwGFjKpiMPgJ0/xiHh3DZLm+jkY7+BFmiG4A1JcXiyHFATBEdxqOKrLfMkR4DoboDsYQ2j4MAR6LIbpOGUKrwxBgnwzRdcCQWtsM+bXPEF2DDLH1zRBfewzRNcAQ27EZ4qvPEF0lhtzOyZBeHYboCjHENviMIb4yDNERGXIb/IQhPR5DdDsz5DbYgyG9fRmi24EhtwGTIb3fM0T3JENuCTdditwHv7yNhoohvWcZovsBZ5DbVlzGyPvnNabNz75pwKrx9vMZxDik932G6L7B0QSXZXYTWasS24u1kWcRHk2CQ3iPGaL7giPI7XRC+ykHFOCQ3ucM0d ...
```

Why is it says:

```
xlink:href="data:image/png
```

If it's not png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a PNG that has been encoded as a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and embeded in a SVG file, utilizing the [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) tag.

From certian details its possible to see this has been produced with Illustrator. Probably someone has placed the PNG into an artboard, choosing not to link but to embed the file, and then exported to SVG.

Comment: I need to place this image on website. Is it bad tone or not?

Comment: Having a PNG in a SVG file in a website means two server requests until the PNG is loaded. You said this was only part of the file, are there other vector elements included? If not, using the bare png would only have the downside that you have to position it anew, since it seems not to fill the SVG viewbox.